# Pandas dataframe how to replace row with one with additional attributes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a method that adds additional attributes to a given pandas series and I want to update a row in the df with the returned series.

Lets say I have a simple dataframe:
`df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2], 'b':[3, 4]})`

```
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

and now I want to replace a row with one with additional attributes, all other rows will show Nan for that column ex:

```
subdf = df.loc[1]
subdf["newVal"] = "foo"  
# subdf is created externally and returned. Now it must be updated.
df.loc[1] = subdf #or something
```

df would look like:

```
   a  b newVal
0  1  3    Nan
1  2  4    foo
```

Comment: I realize in my MVE I could simply go: df.ix[1,"newVal"] = "foo" but I was thinking of a situation where I have a separate pandas series that I am trying to replace a row with (hence the subdf).

Comment: If your MCVE is too minimal, you should consider expanding it. `df.loc[rows, [columns]]` seems to be exactly what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss in generalisation, first `reindex` and then assign with `(i)loc`:

```
df = df.reindex(subdf.index, axis=1)
df.iloc[-1] = subdf

df     
   a  b newVal
0  1  3    NaN
1  2  4    foo
```